# Can you use a Shimano alivio m4000 9speed right shifter for a Shimano alivio m3100 rear derailleur?

Tags: shimano

Can you use a Shimano alivio m4000 9speed right shifter for a Shimano alivio m3100 rear derailleur?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the published specs, both are 9 speed, both are MTB, so yes it should work fine.

Links:

- https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-m3100/RD-M3100-SGS.html
- https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-m4000/SL-M4000-R.html

For 9 speed and fewer, then the distinction between road and MTB is merely marketing.  At 10 speed there are some differences (tiagra!), and at 11 speed things have well gone separate ways.

Comment: Can confirm. That set-up will work perfectly given proper limit settings and indexing on a cassette within specs (11 or 12 to 32 to 36 teeth, referring to small cog and large cog of cassette respectively).